# How to find the Projection of a parabola on a plane with the intersection of a conic

Tags: conic-sections, plane-geometry, python

I'm trying to plot the conic intersection of a plane and a cone in python. I have a plane that is defined as x, y, z=0 and I have a unit vector and an angle at some height which I want to generate a cone from that angle extending out of the unit vector. Then where the extended cone and plane intersect I am interested in the projection of the intersection between the cone and plane. I would expect with angles at around 45 degrees that the projection would be a parabola. I'm trying to plot this in python. I think for the plane I would create a meshgrid for x,y within some bounds, and leave z=0. But I'm not sure how to create an array of points for the cone. If I had that my goal would then to look at the points of intersection between the x_plane, y_plane, and x_cone,y_cone to extract a 2D array of x's and y's that are the data points of the conic intersection, which should be able to be plotted with plt.plot() to get a parabola?

Comment: Your question is not clear: Do you need the equation of the cone? Or something else?

Comment: See if this can be of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4079720/on-the-equation-of-the-ellipse-formed-by-intersecting-a-plane-and-cone

Comment: Note that, to have a parabola, one of the generatrices of the cone must be parallel to the plane.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2368523/find-two-points-and-one-angle-so-that-cone-intersects-the-xy-plane-in-the-para/

Comment: Sorry, to clear things up, I am looking for how to generate an equation for a cone given a 3d unit vector, a height, and an angle. I believe I can generate the equation for the plane, it is just x,y grid values at z=0. I think if I have the equation for a cone I can find the intersection between the arrays of x,ys of the plane and the cone. Then that could be plotted as x,y values of their own in whatever shape needed.

Comment: See here for the equation of the cone: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233966/help-finding-the-equation-of-a-cone-in-space